# Submission of a part of a thesis to a conference?

Tags: paper-submission

I just submitted a part of my thesis to a conference. But in the document, although in fact it is a paper to be submitted to a journal, I have mistakenly left a few words as “in this thesis, my thesis,.. etc”.  Because of the deadline and some timing constraints, I could not find time to replace them. 
Do you think it’s a bad thing to upload a paper with thesis words in it? Would it be a negative consideration in terms of the perspectives of the scientific committee?

Comment: This is suggesting copy and paste and if so was a very bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

It certainly doesn't look good, but it really depends on the quality of the rest of the paper.

- If it's an excellent paper (clear accept), then it will probably be accepted and have a suggestion that those occurrences be removed
- If it's a weak paper (clear reject) then it won't make things worse.

The problems is if it's a borderline paper. It certainly seems sloppy to leave them in, as it's a clear indicator that you did not proof read your conference version before submitting, which reflects quite negatively. So if you're already on the borderline, this could tip the balance towards reject when you would have otherwise been accepted.

That said, this is highly dependent on the reviewers, the program committee, the quality of the conference, etc.

Regardless, it's certainly not career ending: it should not have consequences beyond possible rejection from the conference.

Comment: TLDR it depends

Answer (score 1):

You should note that hardly any paper gets published in the exact form in which it is first submitted. You will most likely get some feedback and an opportunity to improve the paper according to the suggestions of the reviewers. You can take out the references to the thesis at that time.

You can also contact the conference committee (or the program committee) and ask to update the paper prior to review. They may permit that or not, but in the long term it will probably not matter.